# LinearGradient too slow

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am using linear gradient property in background. Every time I change a card (radio), the `_selectedColor`

should change as a radio is a map with a property color `radios![index].color` . Well, it does happen but very slowly. I takes about a minute to gradually change the `_selectedColor` . How can I speed up this process ?

```
VxAnimatedBox()
    .size(context.screenWidth, context.screenHeight)
    .withGradient(
  LinearGradient(
    colors: [
      Colors.blue,
      _selectedColor,
    ],
    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
  ),
)
```

On card change, `_selectedColor` gets updated:

```
onPageChanged: (index) {
  final colorHex = radios![index].color;
  print(colorHex);

  setState(() {
    _selectedColor = Color(int.parse(colorHex));
  });
},
```

I have tried to use transform but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a duration to your animated box like so:

```
VxAnimatedBox()
  .size(context.screenWidth, context.screenHeight)
  .seconds(sec: 2)
  .withGradient(
    LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Colors.blue,
        _selectedColor,
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    ),
  )
```

Notice the added call to the `seconds` methods